# Вызов процедуры самой себя

Tags: delphi, pascal

У меня есть процедура FormShow() которая выполняется при показе нового окна, который рэндомно считывает информацию из файла.
И есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую, я бы хотел вызвать эту же процедуру, точнее код процедуры. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или можно

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject)
begin
  ....
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject)
begin
  FormShow(Form1)
end;
```

Comment: Либо же назначить обоим компонентам один обработчик: Button1.OnClick = FormShow(self);

Comment: Можно, но тогда лучше его обозвать как-то по-другому и добавить примечание, откуда это вызывается. Не ня, когда на нажатие кнопки реагирует метод FormShow =D Не зря ж им такие названия дадены =)

Это не каждый, кто будет смотреть код, сообразит посмотреть таблицу назначений методов для всех элементов, а нигде более она не фигурирует. Да и через некоторое время будут непонятности из-за таких наворотов в коде.

Answer (score 5):

Общий код - в отдельную процедуру, а её вызывайте откуда хотите)

```
procedure TForm1.Nya()
begin
   // Do nya
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject)
begin
   Nya();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject)
begin
   Nya();
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько помню, можно вообще в Object Inspector для OnClick кнопки выбрать метод TForm1.FormShow и даже никакого кода писать не потребуется.